# I am currently removing jquery from my code and I am not able to convert this Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently removing the Jquery from my website but i am not able to successfully convert it to JavaScript. I know its probably very stupid but i am still a beginner. Could anyone help?

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.navbar').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).
    scrollTop() > $('.navbar').height());
});
```

Comment: Some hints: [`document.addEventListener("scroll",` … `)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`document.querySelectorAll(".navbar")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (or `querySelector`), [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods, […`.classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods), [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), etc.

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: I think if you just google `scroll` event, `classList#toggle` `document#querySelector` and you can fairly easy do it just read about. This is not advanced JS and google does not hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
  var isScrolled = document.body.scrollTop > nav.offsetHeight || document.documentElement.scrollTop > nav.offsetHeight;
  nav.classList.toggle("scrolled", isScrolled);
};
```

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

.scrolled .nav-link {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    Navbar
    <a class="nav-link">aaa</a>
    <a class="nav-link">bbb</a>
    <a class="nav-link">ccc</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

We're subscribing to the window's `onscroll` event. We grab a reference to your navbar element using `document.querySelector()`. Then we use that elements height (`offsetHeight`) to determine if it should have the `.scrolled` class. Finally, we use the `toggle()` method on the navbar element's `classList` property.

**UPDATE based on comments:**

If you must have many separate functions to handle the same event, you're better off using the `window.addEventListener()` syntax.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
  var isScrolled = document.body.scrollTop > nav.offsetHeight || document.documentElement.scrollTop > nav.offsetHeight;
  nav.classList.toggle("scrolled", isScrolled);
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // ...
  console.log('scroll b');
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // ...
  console.log('scroll c');
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if i want to use the same function on another class? Having .navbar and .nav-link

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The example in my answer contains an anonymous function to handle the window's scroll event. What is your need?

Comment: I basically had that Jquery code twice, once with .navbar that triggered a change on the color of the complete navbar. And the other one, .nav-link changed the color of the links of the navbar when scrolled. And i want to basically convert both to javascript

Comment: Assuming that your `.nav-link` elements are nested within your `.navbar` element, you can create a CSS rule to apply styles to the `.nav-link` elements when their parent contains the `.scrolled` class. See the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

The first line can be replaced it with an "addEventListener" like this

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
});
```

to replace the toggle function you can use the "classList" property. Save the element in a new variable and then "element.classList.remove('class')" or "element.classList.add('class')

```
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
navbar.classList.remove("scrolled");
navbar.classList.add("scrolled");
```

Use this.scrollY to get the window ScrollY position, and element.clientHeight to get the height of the element including paddings (there are others methods to get the height that can fit more to your needs)

```
 if (this.scrollY > navbar.clientHeight) {}
```

The end result will be something like this

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  navbar.classList.remove("scrolled");
  if (this.scrollY > navbar.clientHeight) {
      navbar.classList.add("scrolled");
  }
});
```